# FIAM/Firebase In-app Messaging can't receive message with Country/Region config

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging, firebase-in-app-messaging

As the title mentioned, the app can't receive/display messages set related to **Country/Region** or  **Languages**.

When using other conditions (**Version, User audience(s), User property,**...) messages can be displayed normally according to analytic events.

This is my message config
[image]
[image]

The app side also doesn't handle anything at all other than implementing and adding `FirebaseInAppMessagingClickListener`, so the problem of why the app can't receive messages set by **Country/Region or Languages** ​​is very confusing.

In case of other conditions (**Version, User audience(s), User property,**...), it can show message normally, and re-install app/clear data can show message again.

With **Country/Region or Languages,** when I tried it on a virtual device, it seemed like the message appeared the first time, then I reinstalled/deleted the data, it stopped showing up, but I'm not sure if it only showed up once. Because under other conditions, deleting app/deleting data will continue to be displayed.

If anyone has had a similar problem or knows what the problem is, please give me some advice, thank you very much.